# System.Drawing does not exist?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to create a validation image using class library in asp.net, but that is not the question.

Anyway, my question is... well... system.drawing does not exist so I cant use "bitmap".
From similar questions, people tell to add reference. But I already did that, restarted my computer etc. It doesn't work.

What can I do besides adding reference? It doesn't work or am I doing it wrong ?

Here is basically what I did:

- Right click to references, which is under solution,
- add reference
- add system.drawing

But still, it does not appear in intellisense or tells me "it does not exist, try adding reference" when I type it manually.

[image: picture]

Comment: Please attach the full sourcecode of the file where you are trying to call into a method in System.Drawing.

Comment: Do you get it by typping `System.Drawing.Bitmap`

Comment: when you write the class name, does a small rectangle under the name appear telling to add the using directive?

Comment: Nope, I dont get it.(when I type system.drawing(with correct cases of course) it does not appear. well, Im just trying to add it to top of namespace. but fine with using it in code so... it still does not appear anyway.

Comment: Are you adding the correct version? If you are on .NET 4, it should be 4.0.0.0.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is you added the reference to the wrong project. Is the Validator.cs file in the project that has the System.Drawing reference?

Answer (score 20):

I suspect that you added the System.Drawing reference to the wrong project. Please verify that  the Validator.cs file in the project that has the System.Drawing reference.

Comment: Brilliant. I had a class library and was adding the reference to the wrong project I thought I was losing it there. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 8):

You can add referrence **'System.Drawing.dll'** to your project.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and solved it, click on the project menu, then Add reference, reference manager will open, then click on the assemblies tab, search for System.Drawing and check it then press ok. it will recognize the package or name space.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled this error even referencing assembly. After thinking i realised that that error produced after adding a class file which is under 'System' folder which i produced on the project folder. That class has ##.System.## namespace as well under the folder. .Net produced error if you have any custom namespace which contains 'System' keyword. Try changing folder name and namespace if u stumbled as well.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the Project tab and then on Add Reference…
[image]

Then select `System.Drawing` or whatever you want.

Comment: this option doesn't exist in my Visual Studio/C# project

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding the reference, you will also need to import it using the `using` statement in the top of your code file:

```
using System.Drawing;
```

Comment: That is a terrible answer, didn't you see his screenshot?  I am having the exact same problem and I can't figure out what is causing it?  I have included the reference and added a using statement at the top of my code.  Yet I can't use the Image namespace in that class?

Comment: @DmainEvent No, I didn't see the screenshot since it wasn't in the original question. It was added later, after I answered. In retrospect, obviously this answer is irrelevant ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should change .NET Framework version to .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered the same problem. I found that a console/class library project cannot add a reference to System.Drawing. When I changed to use a Window Form project, I was able to add a Bitmap with a reference to System.Drawing.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you have not added any user control to your class library project. Add a user control to your class library project, and the error will vanish.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I was trying to add Reference to System.Drawing.dll via System Explorer, but it didn't help me. Finally, I put cursor on the varialbe of type 'Graphics', clicked Ctrl+. or 'Alt+Enter->Refactoring' and select 'using System.Drawing'. I don't understand why and how, but it solved my problem.
[image]